# Angular/Firestore Sum the values of an Array of Objects inside a document

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document inside a firestore collection with several key-values, one of them is an array of objects and i want to calculate the sum of all the values of key "orders" inside the array "sessions" for that id.

```js
{
      id: "asdSDWESHGawhadah",
      name: "John",
      lastName: "Doe",
      age: "20",
      sessions: [

        {
          orders: 1
          date: 2019 - 11 - 24
        },
        {
          orders: 5
          date: 2019 - 11 - 26
        },
        {
          orders: 4,
          date: 2019 - 11 - 29
        },
      ],
    }
```

I haven't been able to show the result of the sum ( 10 in this case) in the HTML.
I tried to do it in the typescript of the component where i call the service that gives me the document, but the variable is an Observable with my Interface so i cant use map or reduce, i know there is a way using RxJs, i can't find a good example to understand, its to complex for my knowledge.
Is there an easy way to obtain the sum result from Firestore directly?

```js
constructor(
private fbservice: FirebaseService,) {  }

  ngOnInit() {

        this.fbpatient$ = this.fbservice.getOnePatient(idPatient);  

  }
```

The getOnePatient method brings me the data that contains all of the sessions with the values i want to sum
but as i said i cant work with fbpatient$ like a normal javascript object cause of the Observable.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by using the RXJS map operator, something like this:

```
mySumObservable$ = this.fbservice.getOnePatient(idPatient).pipe(
  map(patient => {
    return patient.sessions.reduce((sum, session) => sum + session, 0);
  })
);
```

Then you could get the sum out of the mySumObservable$ either by subscribing to it in your code, something like:

```
mySumObservable$.subscribe(sum => this.patientSum = sum);
```

Or by subscribing with the async pipe in your html:

```
<div>{{ (mySumObservable$ | async) }}</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your kind reply, i understand your soultion and i think is the best one but i have a problem with the reduce method after the arrow (sum + session) gives me an error because sum is a number and session is a type IPatient (my interface). The message says Operator '+' can not be applied to types 'number' and {orders: number, date: any, assistance?: string} , i think the problem is that is not taking the numeric value of orders. What could be the solution to this?  i tried (sum + session['order']) but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user SnorreDan i came up with this solution, it works for me altough i dont know if it's the best way or the best practice. Then i subscribe in the HTML as SnorreDan suggested with {{mySumObservable$}}

```js
let sum = 0;
    this.mySumObservable$ = this.fbservice.getOnePatient(idPatient).pipe(
      map((patient) => {
        patient.sessions.forEach((patient) => {
          sum = sum + patient.orders;
        });
        
        return sum;
      })
    ) as any;
```